# angular-chart.js data coming in halfway through the line chart

Tags: angularjs, angular-chart

Is there a way to make the data come in halfway through the chart in angular-chart.js?

**Graph as I want it to look:-**
[image: graph as I want it to look]

Like in the picture above, line 2 comes in at some point later in the graph.

right now my data looks something like this:

```
[
[1, 2, 3, 4],
[0, 1, 2, 3]
]
```

but I want it to look something like this instead:

```
[
[1, 2, 3, 4],
[1, 2, 3]
]
```

and explicitely state that the second set of data should come in at point x1 along the x-axis, or that the second set should use the 3 data points and plot them having a bias towards the right, rather than a bias towards the left.

I've tried looking for it but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

My advice for you is to start by reading some tutorials on d3 and try to make your graph from square one. It will get you closer to your objective, without needing to adapt your ideas to other libraries.

With that being said, you can search for some ideas here:

http://bl.ocks.org/benjchristensen/2579599

It is hard to help you more than this without knowing your code or the library's code.